# VMWare installation on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, vmware, init.d

I've installed vmware 12.5 on my arch linux, but when I tried to run a virtual machine, it showed an error pop up saying:

```
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
```

After search on arch wiki, I ran into [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#.2Fdev.2Fvmmon_not_found) that, as I understand, informed me to configure the auto load of the vmmon module, following the instructions on [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#systemd_services). But even after manually creating the files at `/etc/systemd/system/`, as informed in the instructions, I can't get it to work. I tried running:

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Before and after creating the files, but it throws:

```
sh: /etc/init.d/vmware: No such file or directory
Unable to stop services
```

If anyone already faced this problem or know how to solve it, please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I managed to make it work, here what I did:**

1º Error:

```
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.
```

Was because the *vmmon* kernel module wasn't loaded due to the secure boot loader was active on my PC, which was blocking it. So, instead of disabling it, i added both the *vmmon* and *vmci* kernel modules to my linux kernel by running:

```
$ modprobe vmmon
$ mobprobe vmci
$ modprobe vmnet
```

2º Error:

```
sh: /etc/init.d/vmware: No such file or directory
Unable to stop services
```

Was because the Arch Linux uses *systemd* as the service manager instead of the default *init*. After creating the services as stated [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#systemd_services), I executed:

```
$ mkdir /etc/init.d
$ touch vmware
```

After all that, everything worked! :-)

Comment: Good on you for taking the time to post the answer to your own question.  Thanks for doing this as I'm having issues with getting VMWare working under Arch.

Comment: Where do you got the vmci Kernel-Module? It only seems to be available in vmware-patch, but this has Version 14.0.0. If I try to install it, it removes vmware-workstation (14.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled a bit with getting vmci to work, but solved it at least for vmware-player 14.1.1 with installing this packages:

```
vmware-workstation
open-vm-tools
```

and running this commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start vmware-usbarbitrator
sudo systemctl start vmware-hostd
```